# Early 2008 MacBook pro upgrades

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an early 2008 17 inch MacBook Pro, and I'm trying to upgrade it to run more like a modern laptop. What are the first things to upgrade and some top priorities. Also when would it cross the line where it would just be easier/less expensive to buy a somewhat new macbook. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this might be closed as "opinion-based" but IMO, it's not really worth it.

New SSD, max out the RAM at 6GB, last supported OS El Capitan… it would still be OK for email & a bit  of light word processing, but not so much out in the interwebz, because it has no security updates any more.

Comment: One has to add that the MBP's internal SerialATA interface has a bandwidth of 1.5 Gb/s. This limits the SSD to maybe 120 MB/s r/w. Not every available 2.5" SATA-SSD will work attached to this interface.

Comment: @klanomath - good point, thank you. tbh, I have old Mac Pros here limited to 3GB/s which are still OK, but half that again is going to feel a bit slow, even if it works. I still think, not worth it really.

Comment: You could install Windows 10 and so get security updates.  That is what I did on my 2006 MBP.  Works fine for Office and basic internet but struggles a bit (gets very hot) with Skype/YouTube as the graphics card (ATI X1600) is pretty poor.  I installed a €40 generic SSD and maxed RAM to 3GB.

Comment: @klanomath: Would this [item](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/Firmtek/SATA2SM2E/) allow an external drive to operate at 3 Gb/s? If so, would a external SSD be faster than a external HDD?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hmm, checking the specs of ExpressCard/34, it depends on how Apple engineers connected it to the system bus: 480/1500/3000 Mb/s is possible in theory. Considering the internal 1.5 Gb/s SATA interface, I don't think the highest bandwidth (3.0 Gb/s) was implemented.